# My layout looks different in my browser than it does in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, layout

I am developing a website as a part of my project using Visual Studio 2008. At run time some of the text boxes and buttons dont appear in the same size like in design time, they look elongated and larger.

I am also facing problems when placing various controls during design time, because at run time they appear at different locations in the website.

Comment: Solution: Read a book on web design.

Comment: Solution 2: Design your site in a text editor.

Comment: Are there no solutions for this problem in visual studio??

Comment: I highly doubt it.  In any case, it'd probably be more efficient to test your webpages directly using a web browser instead.  Making websites look good in multiple browsers is hard to begin with -- why make it even more confusing by introducing yet another rendering engine to the mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design-time HTML preview in Visual Studio is horrible and never looks like the final product. I would avoid using it.

The best solution for designing layout in Visual Studio is to code your HTML and CSS in the editor to get a general layout. Then build and publish to your server. Open your page in a good development browser like Chrome or Firefox. Open the development tools and fiddle with the CSS until it looks good in the browser. Do an element at a time and then copy the new CSS to Visual Studio, build/publish again, and refresh your page.

Keep doing this until you have the layout your looking for, and then test in other popular browsers.